# JSF Image servlet doesn't load image

Tags: jsf-2, jpa-2.0, ejb-3.0

I have problem with dispaying image, that loaded via serlvet from database.
I use this class

```
public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 10240;

@EJB
private GoodsDAO goodsDAO;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String stringImageId = request.getParameter("id");

    if (stringImageId == null) {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND); // 404.
        return;
    }
    int imageId = Integer.parseInt(stringImageId);
    Goods goods = goodsDAO.find(imageId);

    if (goods == null) {

        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND); // 404.
        return;
    }

    response.reset();
    response.setBufferSize(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    response.setContentLength(goods.getImage().length);
    response.setHeader("Expires", "Thu, 15 Apr 2010 20:00:00 GMT");

    BufferedOutputStream output = null;

    try {
        output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
        output.write(goods.getImage());
    } finally {
        close(output);
    }
}

private static void close(Closeable resource) {
    if (resource != null) {
        try {
            resource.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

my faces-config

```
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">


<navigation-rule>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>listAllGoods</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/pages/protected/user/listAllGoods.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>

<navigation-rule>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>createGoods</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/pages/protected/admin/createGoods.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>

<navigation-rule>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>createOrder</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/pages/protected/user/createOrder.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>

<application>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>messages</base-name>
        <var>msgs</var>
    </resource-bundle>
</application>
```

my web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>ClothesJSF</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>pages/protected/user/listAllGoods.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>imageServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.servlet.ImageServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>imageServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/image/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
        <param-value>51200</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

I load my image with this code:

```
<h:graphicImage id="zoomImage" value="image?id=#{goods.id}"
                style="cursor:pointer" width="70" />
```

I have problem with displaying image on none-home pages. When I open page:

```
http://localhost:8080/ClothesJSF/
```

all my images normally were loaded from database.
If i open page

```
http://localhost:8080/ClothesJSF/pages/protected/user/listAllGoods.xhtml
```

that equal to my home page my image won't be loaded. This problem also occured on all others pages.

I think that I have problem with image-servlet settings

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>imageServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/image/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and maybe I need other regular expression in url-pattern, but I couldn't figure out it. 
I will be glad to any advice. Thanks you.

**UPDATE** If i will use path like this in all image:

```
<h:graphicImage id="zoomImage" value="http://localhost:8080/ClothesJSF/image?id=#
{goods.id}" style="cursor:pointer" width="70" />
```

It will work, but if i will use #{request.contextPath}/ this won't work. Maybe I need made some preference changes if I want #{request.contextPath}/image?id=# would work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `<h:graphicImage value>` does not start with a scheme or `/`, then it's relative to the current request URL. Imagine that you're opening the page by `http://localhost:8080/ClothesJSF/faces/page.xhtml` and the page in question has a

```
<h:graphicImage value="image?id=1" />
```

then JSF will generate a

```
<img src="image?id=1" />
```

which effectively becomes relative to `http://localhost:8080/ClothesJSF/faces/` and the webbrowser will attempt to download the actual image from `http://localhost:8080/ClothesJSF/faces/image?id=1`, which thus only ends up in an error. If you have paid attention to webbrowser's builtin HTTP traffic montitor, you'd have noticed that.

You need to let it start with `/` to make it relative to the context path.

```
<h:graphicImage value="/image?id=1" />
```

This way JSF will generate

```
<img src="/ClothesJSF/image?id=1" />
```

Which is right. Note that the `#{request.contextPath}` is not necessary. The `<h:graphicImage>` already takes care of it transparently. You only need that in "plain HTML" resource elements like `<a>`, `<img>`, `<link>`, `<iframe>`, etc.

Comment: Thanks you, its work! I'm only 2 weeks working with JSF, JPA, etc, but I have already read dozen of you articles and you saved a lot of my time. You are doing a great job, thanks you very much.
PS When i wrote this post i thought that probably you would answer it:D.
PPS Sorry for my english